# how can i ensure innodb thread safety

Tags: python, mysql, thread-safety, locking, innodb

I have an InnoDB table which lists a bunch of files which need to be processed.

The python script which handles the processing basically does this:

1. get next file which has status = 'unprocessed'
2. set the status to 'processing'
3. call some C++ script to process that file
4. mark it as 'processed'
5. end

This python script will be called multiple times, and so I am somewhat concerned that there could be some problem at step 1 and 2, where process B will get the same row from the db as process A before process A has the time to update the status in step 2.

I am guessing the Python GIL doesn't help me here since the interpreter will release the GIL when doing the SQL (right?).  And from what I am reading, doing table locks on InnoDB doesn't work.  Will the row-level locking take care of the issue here?  If not, what are my other options?

Could I simply do "from threading import Lock" and add

```
with lock:
    update_file_status(file_id, "processing")
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement - this will aquire exclusive lock on the row and won't allow other `SELECT FOR UPDATE` on the same row.